# WiFiの復号をtsharkで行うには

Tags: tshark, wireshark

WPA２のassociation時の 4way handshakeがキャプチャできており、SSIDとパスワードもわかっている場合、Wiresharkで復号することができました。

復号処理をtsharkで行う場合の、式の記載方法をご教示いただけないでしょうか。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
tshark -nr input.pcap -o wlan.enable_decryption:TRUE -o 'uat:80211_keys:"wpa-pwd","<Password>:<SSID>"'
```

[こちらの回答](https://ask.wireshark.org/questions/24249/decrypt-wpa-with-tshark)を参考にしました。`TShark 1.12.1`で動作することを確認しています。